# How to get r.drain to run in QGIS/GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, cost-path

I use the GRASS GIS extensions for QGIS (QGIS version 2.12.3 with GRASS 6.4) and I have a problem with the r.drain algorithm: I simply cannot make it work with a given starting point as a vector point.

To put it simple, here is what I try to achieve:

•   Insert a cost-raster

•   Insert a vector point

•   Calculate least cost path

I managed to get it to run when I enter the coordinates for the starting point manually, but since I want to use r.drain in the Model Builder of QGIS, that’s not the solution I am looking for.

Here is the log message:

```
Algorithmus r.drain - Traces a flow through an elevation model on a raster map. startet...
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external -r input="C:\Users\M73C7~1.THY\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2dc0bf84d6904a2e98cf88aa7c96f01b\65449bc0c78d4f88bd9ccb81f73dd7db\outputALGGRASSR.COST1.tif" band=1 output=tmp14538092333818 --overwrite -o
g.region n=5728838.9502 s=5642436.07274 e=3563614.80147 w=3517244.6193 res=30
r.drain input="tmp14538092333818" coordinate="0,0" vector_points="T:/End_Netzpunkt.shp" output=output31af3facd469466da5d085a4022c5830 --overwrite
g.region rast=output31af3facd469466da5d085a4022c5830
r.out.gdal -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output31af3facd469466da5d085a4022c5830 output="C:\Users\M73C7~1.THY\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2dc0bf84d6904a2e98cf88aa7c96f01b\87ddeef3905446ef8f464853f27a795f\output.tif"
```

GRASS commands output:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set HOME=C:\Users\
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set GISRC=C:\Users\.qgis2\\processing\processing.gisrc 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set GRASS_SH=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\bin\sh.exe 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set PATH=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\msys\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\msys\bin 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set WINGISBASE=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3  
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set GISBASE=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set GRASS_PROJSHARE=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\share\proj 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set GRASS_MESSAGE_FORMAT=gui 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>if "" == "" set PATH=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\msys\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\msys\bin 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>if not "" == "" set PATH=C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\bin;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\msys\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\msys\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\msys\bin 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set GRASS_VERSION=6.4.0
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>if not "" == "" goto langset 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`"C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\winlocale"`) DO @set LANG=%i 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>set PYTHONPATH=;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python;C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\n 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="MAPSET=PERMANENT" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION=temp_location" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="LOCATION_NAME=temp_location" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GISDBASE=C:\Users\M73C7~1.THY\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2dc0bf84d6904a2e98cf88aa7c96f01b\grassdata" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.gisenv.exe set="GRASS_GUI=text" 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs" 
GRASS_INFO_MESSAGE(3236,1): Die Standard Region wurde auf die neue Projektion aktualisiert. Wenn Sie aber mehrere Mapsets haben, sollten Sie `g.region -d` in jedem ausführen, um die Einstellungen von der Standardregion zu übernehmen. 
GRASS_INFO_END(3236,1) 
GRASS_INFO_MESSAGE(3236,2): Projektionsinformationen aktualisiert 
GRASS_INFO_END(3236,2) 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>r.external -r input="C:\Users\M73C7~1.THY\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2dc0bf84d6904a2e98cf88aa7c96f01b\65449bc0c78d4f88bd9ccb81f73dd7db\outputALGGRASSR.COST1.tif" band=1 output=tmp14538092333818 --overwrite -o 
GRASS_INFO_WARNING(972,1): Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
GRASS_INFO_END(972,1) 
GRASS_INFO_MESSAGE(972,2): Importing band 1 of 1... 
GRASS_INFO_END(972,2) 
GRASS_INFO_MESSAGE(972,3): Link zur Rasterkarte erzeugt 
GRASS_INFO_END(972,3) 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.region n=5728838.9502 s=5642436.07274 e=3563614.80147 w=3517244.6193 res=30 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>r.drain input="tmp14538092333818" coordinate="0,0" vector_points="T:/End_Netzpunkt.shp" output=output31af3facd469466da5d085a4022c5830 --overwrite 
GRASS_INFO_MESSAGE(3472,1): Oberflächen-/Hydrologischer-Abfluß ausgewählt 
GRASS_INFO_END(3472,1) 
GRASS_INFO_WARNING(3472,2): Startpunkt 1 ist außerhalb der aktuellen Region. 
GRASS_INFO_END(3472,2) 
Ungültiger Dateiname. Das Zeichen ist nicht erlaubt. 
GRASS_INFO_ERROR(3472,3): Vektorkarte nicht gefunden. 
GRASS_INFO_END(3472,3) 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>g.region rast=output31af3facd469466da5d085a4022c5830 
GRASS_INFO_ERROR(3560,1): Rasterkarte konnte nicht gefunden werden. 
GRASS_INFO_END(3560,1) 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>r.out.gdal -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" input=output31af3facd469466da5d085a4022c5830 output="C:\Users\M73C7~1.THY\AppData\Local\Temp\processing2dc0bf84d6904a2e98cf88aa7c96f01b\87ddeef3905446ef8f464853f27a795f\output.tif" 
GRASS_INFO_ERROR(1796,1): Rasterkarte oder Gruppe nicht gefunden. 
GRASS_INFO_END(1796,1) 
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin>exit 
Converting outputs
Lade Ergebnis Layer
```

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Least cost path
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Answer (score 2):

I tried out the **r.drain** algorithm in my QGIS (version 2.12, GRASS 6.4) with the raster dem and point (in blue) of below image.

[image]

After running the **r.drain** grass module with successfully finish.

[image]

I copied and pasted the complete **r.drain** command at the GRASS shell; with another name for the output raster.

```
r.drain input=utah_demUTM2@javier output=out_raster "coordinate=366466.04693, 4461604.75446"
```

After running the command in this way, I also had a successfully (and the same) result:

[image]

If you want other parameters at your **r.drain** command, you have a detailed explanation in the Module Manual:

[image]

Comment: First, thank you xunilk for your answer! But the thing I try to achieve is getting r.drain to run without entering the coordinates of the starting point manually, but to insert a shapefile containing a starting point and then let it run with that point. I hope you get my “point” ;)

Comment: I understood. So, I think that you need **grass.script** with python for retrieving the shapefile point coordinates.